# HTTP inbound endpoint debug messages

Tags: mule, inbound

When running a http inbound endpoint, is it normal to see these debug messages repeated every 4 or more than 4 seconds?

```
DEBUG IdleConnectionHandler [HttpClient-connection-cleaner-connector.http.mule.default]: Checking for connections, idleTimeout: 1373548231273
```

Answer (score 1):

The http connector used to leak somme connections as per [MULE-6032](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6032)

To address this a couple of things have been done, being one the introduction of a thread that cleans the connection left in a CLOSE_WAIT status.

You can find a diff for that issue [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/commit/f30671055865398bac3c1817513189aba4ebbca3)